# How to Convert FXML to JAVA

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I created a .fxml file using javafx scene builder in NetBeans.

How can I convert .fxml file in NetBeans to .java?
Is that any program to convert it?

I am not very good in fxml so I want to use .java file to code my javafx app.

Comment: if you are using NetBeans there is a plugin which does the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't any support for this kind of thing. The idea is that you are using FXML to visually layout your UI and then connecting it to java using a controller class.

Sidenote: We at e(fx)clipse started a build addon that allows you to converter FXML-Files into Java-Files - because of performance reasons on embedded devices.

Comment: @tomsontom Could you elaborate on this addon? Is it a tool or library which could be wrapped by a Maven plugin? Or will it only work in Eclipse?

Comment: The idea is to have it as a library you can integrate into your build process (not matter which tool you use, we'll most likely out of the box support ant) - because we are currently moving our codebase to eclipse.org the work has been stalled a bit but I hope we can pickup speed in 1-2 weeks.

Comment: I've published a first pre alpha version. See http://www.mail-archive.com/openjfx-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg01589.html

Answer (score 5):

> Is that any program to convert it?

Yes. Netbeans [FXML 2 JAVA Converter](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304040347/http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/68619/fxml-2-java-converter) *via Archive.org 2021.03.04 capture for `plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/68619/fxml-2-java-converter`*.

Comment: Pre-Apache plugin portal is not accessible now. Can you please share a google drive link ?

Comment: @MadushanPerera updated answer to use Archive.org link.

Comment: @marc-medley not a valid link again

Comment: At this moment, the archive.org link loaded ok. And, the 8.2 tab download occured ok. The 8.1 tab does not have an associated download.