# JavaFX Scene Builder Alternative without FXML file

Tags: java, class, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Do you know if there is a way to make Scene Builder work with Java classes instead of FXML files? (Java classes are much faster to load into a program than FXML. This is sometimes very useful when a page is very heavy).
Otherwise, do you know a tool like Scene Builder that allows you to create a graphical interface easily but generating Java code rather than FXML files?

I know that there are tools to transform a .FXML file into a Java class but it requires an additional manipulation each time I add a graphical component to my page. It's not really practical.

Comment: please add the code snippet that you have tried if you have any

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149843/how-to-convert-fxml-to-java might help. It's an old answer though.

Comment: unownsp 

Sorry for the delay in answering, I've been very busy lately (business trip...).
So, I don't have any piece of code to give, it can work with any JavaFX code. I just need to have a graphical page creator (like SceneBuilder) that doesn't create the pages in .FXML but in .java.
Or a 100% automatic converter between SceneBuilder and Netbeans.

Comment: sedrick 

For the link you provided, I already know this solution, the problem is that it is necessary to transform the .FXML file each time a modification is made. Moreover, I am French and there are accents on some letters, however, the Netbeans plugin does not support accents, so it is necessary to modify all texts manually.